Is it possible to tab complete by whole word in Bash
Suppose I have filenames as follows on my Linux system:
$ ls -1
file-index-00012.txt
file-index-00345.txt
question.txt

I start typing, where "|" represents the cursor:
$ cat fil|

If I press tab once, Bash partially completes filenames:
$ cat file-index-00|

If I press tab twice more, it shows candidate filenames:
$ cat file-index-00
file-index-00012.txt  file-index-00345.txt
$ cat file-index-00|

The problem with this is that I have to check how many digits have been partially completed, before entering the remaining ones.  For example, the first time I get a "file-index-01000.txt" in this directory, I have to enter an additional digit:
$ cat file-index-0
file-index-00012.txt  file-index-00345.txt  file-index-01000.txt  
$ cat file-index-0|

Is it possible to make Bash stop completing at the start of the word (separated by hyphen, underscore or whitespace) like this:
$ cat file-index-
file-index-00012.txt  file-index-00345.txt
$ cat file-index-|


You might be interested in trying bash's readline menu-complete.

TAB tries to complete the text. If the goal is just to list possible filename completions, try Meta - ? or Esc - ? or C-x /. (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Commands-For-Completion)
